# Oracle Schema Restrictions

Tags: c#, oracle, linq

I want Oracle restrictions like we have in Sql server //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366(v=vs.110).aspx/
below is my method but this is taking too much time in retrieving data

```
    public override IEnumerable<IColumnInformation> GetTableColumnList(ITableInformation table)
    {
        var result = new List<IColumnInformation>();

        // if the table is flagged as excluded bail with empty list
        if (table.Exclude)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var strb = new OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder(this.ConnectionString);
        DataTable columns;
        using (var connection = new OracleClient.OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            // Connect to the database then retrieve the schema information.
            connection.Open();
            columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns");
            if (columns != null && columns.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                columns.AsEnumerable().ToList()
                    .ForEach(t => result.Add(new ColumnInformation(
                        t.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"),
                        t.IsNull("LENGTH") ? 0 : t.Field<int>("LENGTH"),
                        null, 
                        t.Field<string>("OWNER"),
                        false, 
                        table)));
                }
        }
        return result;
    }
public ColumnInformation(string name, int length, Type type, string databaseType, bool exclude = false, ITableInformation parent = null)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Length = length;
            this.Type = type;
            this.DbType = databaseType;
            this.Exclude = exclude;
            this.Parent = parent;
          }
```

where :ColumnInformation is the class which has  constructor.

i have following questions for getting the columns details for the table in oracle:

1. Do we have Schema Restrictions in oracle like sql server?
2. That linq is giving me error of type specfications.
3. Data table is getting data in more than five minutes.

.
Any help!!

Comment: Can you do this on a table by table basis?  I use the following code: DataTable _dt = connection.GetSchema("Columns", new string[3] { _owner, _tableName, null }); this dramatically reduces the time required to read the schema information.  Iterate the datatable just for what you need for the task.

Comment: yes did in same way. thanks